# Force unwrapped optional doesn't crash. Why not?

Tags: swift

Here is a User model

```
class User: NSObject, NSCoding {
    var userID: String!
    var username: String!
    var password: String!
    var token: String!

    override init() {
    }
}

var user: User?
user.password = pass
user.username = "foo"
user.userID = "bar"
```

When I create the `user`, I don't set the `token` property. Then I try to access the `token` in the example below. My understanding is this way of accessing the `token` is only checking if `user` is nil but not checking if `token` is nil.

```
user?.token
```

I thought this would crash based on how I've set the properties as implicitly unwrapped optionals?

Comment: Something looks off. 
var user = User?
let user = User() You are declaring this variable twice. It shouldn't compile. And var user = User? isn't even valid syntax.

Comment: Sorry I’ve corrected the error

Comment: Practically you don't force unwrap anything. Please read what [Optional Chaining](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH21-ID245) is and how it works. And never, never declare properties in a class as IUO as an alibi not to write an initializer. `override init() {)` does not count.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yeah I was just playing around with different scenarios. I wouldn't do this in an actual project.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't force-unwrapped anything. You've declared `token` as *implicitly unwrapped*, but that doesn't mean it's forced to be unwrapped. It's possible to use an implicitly-unwrapped optional to do something like check if it's nil without unwrapping the nil value and crashing. Something like `if user!.token == nil` is fine even if `token` is declared like this.

Comment: Learned something new today.  Even checking an implicitly unwrapped nil enum case won't crash. `var someEnum: SomeEnum! = nil; if someEnum == .someCase {}` won't crash.  Which is essentially the example you gave, `if nil == .someCase`.

Answer (score 0):

It is normal not to crash because the variable `user` hasn't been initialised. `user?.token` sees that user is nil, so the result will be nil. This is called optional chaining. You can read more [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html).
If you want it to crash, you should `init` a `User` object before trying to access the token field.